# No definition of [boost] for OS version [xenial]

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm installing ROS kinetic from source code on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, by following instructions on http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source

However when I proceed to below step, I got strange errors.

```
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:

roslaunch: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version [xenial]
rosconsole: No definition of [boost] for OS version [xenial]
roslisp: No definition of [boost] for OS version [xenial]
catkin: No definition of [python-argparse] for OS version [xenial]
message_filters: No definition of [boost] for OS version [xenial]
rosmake: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version [xenial]
rostime: No definition of [boost] for OS version [xenial]
roslib: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version [xenial]
rosgraph: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version [xenial]
roscreate: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version [xenial]
cpp_common: No definition of [boost] for OS version [xenial]
rostest: No definition of [boost] for OS version [xenial]
rospy: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version [xenial]
rosunit: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version [xenial]
rospack: No definition of [boost] for OS version [xenial]
roswtf: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version [xenial]
rosbag: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version [xenial]
rosclean: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version [xenial]
rosbag_storage: No definition of [boost] for OS version [xenial]
rosmsg: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS version [xenial]
```

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336685/no-definition-of-%5Bboost%5D-for-os-version-%5Bxenial%5D/) by [uestclx](https://answers.ros.org/users/48749/uestclx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2019-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is solved by upgrading system libraries. And below tools are in the upgrade list:

- python-catkin-pkg
- python-rosdep
- python-rosdistro
- python-rosinstall
- python-rosinstall-generator
- python-rospkg
- python-vcstools
- python-wstool

After the upgrade, all worked smoothly.

---

Originally posted by [uestclx](https://answers.ros.org/users/48749/uestclx/) with karma: 18 on 2019-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0